# Cant access Ubuntu server via SSH after setting UFW policy

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, ufw

I ran the command

```
ufw allow from server_1 proto tcp to any port 22
```

in my second server, but now I can't ssh back into the server. What am I doing wrong? I used `ssh ubuntu@server_ip` from server_1 but can't get in.

Comment: "can't get in" might be due to several possible reasons. Don't summarize - show us real output, please. Run through the usual checklist: Are server sshd settings correct? Did you restart the sshd service? Did you verify that sshd is properly bound to the right port on the server? Does the user have an account on the server? Does the server firewall permit ssh connections? Is the client looking for the correct machine? Can the client ping the server? Does the client firewall permit outgoing connections? Is the client using the correct password/key?

Comment: The goal was allow only server_1 access to server_2 and I ran the command "ufw allow from server_1 proto tcp to any port 22" on server_2. I exited server 2 but I am unable to ssh back into server_2 in order to run any commands on it

Comment: Please do NOT add new information in comments. Comments are not really intended for conversation. Comments are intended to help you ask a better, clearer, more-answerable question.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you are completely locked out of a REMOTE server because you changed the firewall rules?

Comment: yes I am locked out

Comment: Are you asking for help getting access to your system? Or are you asking hypothetically about what you might have done better for next time?

Comment: both, I believed setting the ufw rule would allow me to be able to reconnect from the specified server but I am unable to. So yes, I want to get back into the server and correct my mistake and learn from it.

Comment: Get back in how? Your're locked out. Somebody must go to the server's actual location, plug in a keyboard and display to the actual machine, login, and undo what you did. Unless you're just renting a VPS, of course, in which case go into your management page and trash it and start over. Lesson: Limit access using good security habits, including ssh keys. Firewalls do only one job well - limit them to that job. Also keep proper notes and backups so you can easily wipe/reinstall/restore in about an hour without a long journey.

Comment: Have you enabled ufw service using ```bash
sudo ufw enable
``` The whole flow to enable a rule would look like this: ```bash
sudo ufw <some rule>
sudo ufw enable
``` If you are locked to ssh into the server. Can you please mention where is server is leased from (AWS, DigitalOcean, Rackspace) or is self-hosted?